# how to cutumize audiance reach for a multilingual website

Tags: http, multilingual

I am working with a website www.ieleads.com . the website has multilingual functionality on it in English, Arabic,Chinese. But here we don't have language-specific url like if a page opens in English and you change it in Chinese then there no changes occurs in url structure. Now I looking for a way if a visitor who has preference for Arabic or Chinese in browser or search engine then he shows relevant version of website in default.

can it possible without having change in url structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for HTTP header  [`Accept-Language`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation)